# Resource handler returned message: "Lambda function aws-node-express-api-project-dev-api could not be found"

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless

`PS D:\Project\Serveless\aws-node-express-api-project> serverless deploy

Deploying aws-node-express-api-project to stage dev (us-east-1)

× Stack aws-node-express-api-project-dev failed to deploy (41s)
Environment: win32, node 18.15.0, framework 3.33.0, plugin 6.2.3, SDK 4.3.2
Credentials: Local, "default" profile
Docs:        docs.serverless.com
Support:     forum.serverless.com
Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues`

Comment: npm install -g serverless@3.31.0 (no problem already solved)